# Sharing image from resources into intent Xamarin android

Tags: android, image, share, java-io

I am trying to share image from resources with other apps (like Viber or Facebook).

I used the code below to try and do this, but it is failing:

```
            Bitmap bitmapToShare = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Application.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.A1);
            Java.IO.File pictureStorage = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures);
            Java.IO.File noMedia = new Java.IO.File(pictureStorage, ".nomedia");
            if (!noMedia.Exists())
                noMedia.Mkdirs();
            string imageName = "shared_image" + System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary() + ".Jpeg";

            Stream output = Application.Context.OpenFileOutput(imageName,FileCreationMode.WorldReadable);
            bitmapToShare.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, output);
            output.Flush();
            output.Close();

            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(noMedia, imageName);

            shareIntent.SetType("image/*");
            shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Uri.FromFile(file));
            shareIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
```

For what it's worth, the file is not saved after (output.close;). Why is this failing?

Comment: What error message are you getting? http://www.sscce.org

Comment: There is not error messages , just " file not found " ,,, and  when  i go to the Directory i found it created (Directory) but there is no files inside it .